# Is it correct to say "if not doing so"?

Tags: grammar

I think the following sentence is correct.

> 1. **The box can be put down there if it/the box does not block the way.**

I am wondering if it is grammatical to say

> 2. *"The box can be put down there if not blocking the way."*

Comment: Welcome to ELL stack exchange!  This is an interesting question. What do you mean by “it/the box” in example sentence #1?    The reader understands that “it” means the box, so you’d never need to use `the box` at that location.

Comment: OK. I meant we can say "if it does not block the way" or "if the box does not block the way". I agree with you. The latter one is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, it’s grammatically correct, but sounds formal

Sentence two is adequate:

> 2. ✔️ **OK:** The box can be put down there if not blocking the way.

This is also grammatically fine:

> 3. ✔️ **OK:** If not blocking the way, the box can be put down there.

However, it sounds like a very formal register of English, as if it’s a set of written directions in an instruction manual.

For a more natural sound, try:

> 4. ✔️ **Yes:** The box can be put down there if it doesn’t block the way.

Or:

> 5. ✔️ **Yes:** The box can be put down there if it isn’t in the way.

All of the above sentences are in **passive voice** — (“can be put”). That makes it sound very abstract.

If you can, be direct and use the **active voice**:

> 6. ✔️**Best:** If it won’t be in the way, **you can put** the box down there.

Or even...

> 7. ✔️ If it won’t be in the way, **put** the box down there.

The active voice (#6-7) requires a **subject** — *you*, or *they*, or *the movers*, for example.  If you don’t know **who** will be **doing** the “putting” (the subject), this isn’t available to you.